# Plotly show info of all elements when a toggle button is activated

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

[image]
Current: As you may know, in Plotly it is possible to show the info of a bar when hovering on it.

Question: Is there any plotly function or parameter that I can call/set to show all info elements.

Problem: I have stacked bars and all numbers of the stacked bars are expected to appear with the same size regardless of the thickness of the bars. Because some bars are to thin, the font size is becoming small and not readable. The only way to show the value of this thin bars is by hovering on it. But since we have many stack bars (spreaded in x axis) we cannot hover on all stack bars at once. So I expect to have a button that can show all the information of all bars at one click :)

Hope the explanation is understanable :)
Please ask for more detail :)
Super grateful for any helps :)

Question: Is there any plotly function or parameter that I can call/set to show all info elements.

Comment: Not really a direct answer to your question. But the fact that some of the stacked bars are squished I think indicates that your actual issue is how to handle outliers in your data set. Maybe this could be solved just by just using a logarithmic y axis or other tweaks to your y axis.

Comment: Maybe a stacked bar chart is not even the right fit for your data. Ideally you pick the graph type that fits your data best. I recommend thinking about this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but we must use stacked bar chart here :(

Comment: In that case try the other thing I mentioned, try changing the y axis to be logarithmic. I think the approach where you show all the hover tooltips is not a good idea. If you do that there's no point in having the bars.